# Handle exception after reaching max attempts in resilience4j-retry using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resilience4j, resilience4j-retry

I have a scenario I want to log each retry attempt and when the last one fails (i.e. `maxAttempts` reached) a exception is thrown and let's say an entry to a database is created.

I try to achieve this using Resilience4j-retry with Spring Boot, therefore I use `application.yml` and annotations.

```
@Retry(name = "default", fallbackMethod="fallback")
@CircuitBreaker(name = "default", fallbackMethod="fallback")
public ResponseEntity<List<Person>> person() {
    return restTemplate.exchange(...);               // let's say this always throws 500
}
```

The fallback logs the cause of the exception into an application log.

```
public ResponseEntity<?> fallback(Exception e) {
    var status = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    var cause = "Something unknown";
    if (e instanceof ResourceAccessException) {
        var resourceAccessException = (ResourceAccessException) e;
        if (e.getCause() instanceof ConnectTimeoutException) {
            cause = "Connection timeout";
        }
        if (e.getCause() instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {
            cause = "Read timeout";
        }
    } else if (e instanceof HttpServerErrorException) {
        var httpServerErrorException = (HttpServerErrorException) e;
        cause = "Server error";
    } else if (e instanceof HttpClientErrorException) {
        var httpClientErrorException = (HttpClientErrorException) e;
        cause = "Client error";
     } else if (e instanceof CallNotPermittedException) {
        var callNotPermittedException = (CallNotPermittedException) e;
        cause = "Open circuit breaker";
    }
    var message = String.format("%s caused fallback, caught exception %s", 
        cause, e.getMessage());
    log.error(message);                                         // application log entry
    throw new MyRestException (message, e);
}
```

When I call this method `person()` the retry happens as `maxAttempt` configured. I expect my custom runtime `MyRestException` is caught on each retry and thrown on the last one (when `maxAttempt` is reached), so I wrap the call in the try-catch.

```
public List<Person> person() {
    try {
        return myRestService.person().getBody();
    } catch (MyRestException ex) {
        log.error("Here I am ready to log the issue into the database");
        throw new ex;
    }
}
```

Unfortunatelly, the retry seems to be ignored as the fallback encounters and rethrows the exception that is immediatelly caught with my `try-catch` instead of the Resilience4j-retry mechanism.

How to achieve the behavior when the `maxAttempts` is hit? Is there a way to define a specific fallback method for such case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you catch and map exceptions to `MyRestException` inside of your Service methods, e.g. `myRestService.person()`?
It makes your configuration even simpler, because you only have to add `MyRestException` to the configuration of your RetryConfig and CircuitBreakerConfig.

Spring RestTemplate also has mechanisms to register a custom ResponseErrorHandler, if you don't want to add the boilerplate code to every Service method. -> https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-error-handling

I would not map `CallNotPermittedException` to `MyRestException`. You don't want to retry when the CircuitBreaker is open. Add `CallNotPermittedException` to the list of ignored exceptions in your RetryConfig.

I think you don't need the fallback mechanism at all. I thing mapping an exception to another exception is not a "fallback".

Comment: Thanks for the answr! I concluded to exception handling without fallbacks at the service layer, however I wanted to avoid the boilerplate code to every method - RestTemplate error handling mechanism is good, except it cannot handle timeout errors (`ConnectTimeoutException`, `SocketTimeoutException`...), only the server/client ones as long as `ClientHttpResponse` must be passed. Do you have an idea to deal with that?

Comment: If the answer helps, please accept it ;)
You could use our `SupplierUtils.andThen` and a custom resultHandler function to map `ResourceAccessException` to a `MyRestException`.

Comment: I want to avoid the mixing of the `application.yml`+annotations configuration with the functional decorators configuration as long as I find the annotations easier to use. I have wrapped each `RestTemplate` call in the error handling. That method (rest call + error handling wrapper) is called in a method annotated with the Resilience4j annotations and the retry truly works as I wanted. Would you check this snippet out if it's a good pracice in terms of Resilience4j? https://www.codepile.net/pile/RB5dqQWM

Comment: Yes, that looks fine